# Resultados em formato de tabela no Matlab

Tags: matlab

Ao simular um programa no Matlab, é possível apresentar os resultados em formato de tabela?

*Output* do programa:

```
Nível de tensão (V): 200.6000 199.5000 231.1000 198.8000 200.6000 200.4000 
Data e hora: 21-Aug-2014 18:06:00 23-Aug-2014 18:06:00 24-Aug-2014 06:06:00 27-Aug-2014 08:36:00 29-Aug-2014 14:21:00 30-Aug-2014 07:36:00
```

Formato desejado:

```
Data e hora                 Tensão
20-Aug-2014 09:15:00         225
20-Aug-2014 09:30:00         222
```

Comment: @Omni obrigada pela sugestão. Já editei a minha pergunta.

Comment: @Omni é isso mesmo.

Comment: Os vetores 'Tensão' e 'Data e hora' tem 200 posições cada um. Gostaria de apresentar os resultados uma coluna ao lado da outra, mas como não consegui, primeiro imprimo o vetor 'Data e hora' e abaixo o vetor 'Tensão'.

Comment: Veja a [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38668/8113) do @wanderson, faz o que pretende.

Comment: Infelizmente a versão do Matlab que eu estou usando não tem o comando Table.

Comment: qual versao do matlab e que esta a usar?

Comment: Matlab 7.12.0 (R2011a)

Answer (score 1):

Viva.

Veja o seguinte exemplo.

```
resultados = {'Data e hora','Tensão'};
resultados{2,1} = '20-Aug-2014 09:15:00';
resultados{2,2} = '225';
resultados{3,1} = '20-Aug-2014 09:30:00';
resultados{3,2} = '222';
resultados
```

Depois é só usar um índice para controlar automaticamente a linha onde vai adicionar novos dados, ou seja,

```
resultados{i,1} = 'NOVA_DATA';
resultados{i,2} = 'NOVA_TENSAO';
```

Espero ter ajudado ;)

PS(1):

Será que isto faz o que quer?

```
datas = ['1';'2';'3'];
tensao = [1,2,3];
resultados = {'Data e hora','Tensão'};
for i=1:size(datas,1)
      resultados{i+1,1} = datas(i);
      resultados{i+1,2} = tensao(i);
end
resultados
```

Comment: 'Data e hora' e 'Tensao' são vetores de 200 posições, neste caso, o que devo fazer para imprimir os resultados em formato de tabela?

Comment: Acho que a resposta do wanderson responde à sua pergunta. Se não responder explique-se um pouco melhor sff.

Comment: Mas a versão do Matlab que utilizo, não possui a função Table. (Matlab 7.12.0 (R2011a))

Comment: Necessita dos dados numa tabela ou apenas quer imprimir os dados no formato de tabela?

Em todo o caso veja o PS(1) no post principal.

Comment: Apenas tenho que imprimir os dados em formato de tabela.

Comment: Já experimentou o meu método? Eu acho que funciona para o seu caso mas só você o pode dizer!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o comando table de forma a não só exibir de forma tabular os dados como também armazená-los de forma tabular.

Ex.:

T = table(['M';'F';'M'],[45;32;34],...
    {'NY';'CA';'MA'},logical([1;0;0]),...
    'VariableNames',{'Gender' 'Age' 'State' 'Vote'})

T =

```
Gender    Age    State    Vote 
______    ___    _____    _____

M         45     'NY'     true 
F         32     'CA'     false
M         34     'MA'     false
```

Mais detalhes pode ser obtido no help do comando [table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html?refresh=true).